# Filling up your hard drive to securely remove trash

Tags: hard-drive, trash

Let's say I had personal information and put it in my Trash. Then, I cleared my Trash.

I believe that when you delete files from your Trash, it only removes the files' information from the filesystem and keeps the data on the hard drive and  software such as PhotoRec can recover it, until of course another process overwrites this data.

If I filled up my hard drive with a file full of zeros, would that completely overwrite the data from these 'deleted' files?

Comment: Not with absolute certainty. Some filesystems reserve part of the capacity. Most hard disks do so as well. Much also depends on how determined your attacker is.

Comment: But obviously if it could be written to in the first place by an application, then how can it any of the space be reserved?

Comment: HD or SSD may have a bearing on this, but the old 'overwrite it a million times' is fairly pointless these days. Just encrypt the entire drive, then any deleted data is as deleted as it can be.

Comment: The drive firmware prevents you from getting at all of the space on the drive, and hoards unavailable space to replace failed sectors. Also, overwriting with zeros, or 0xDEADBEEF, is not adequate, as tools exist (national law enforcement as well as commercial establishments) to see what the previous value was.

Comment: See this page....https://www.pcworld.com/article/2464163/how-to-securely-overwrite-deleted-files-with-a-built-in-windows-tool.html

Comment: @K7AAY I still don't understand that. How can the drive frmware prevent me from overwriting data the operating system has made? And Moab, thank you.

Comment: Sorry, I meant firmware. Sorry about this. It's very confusing to me. I thought that the operating system had all the access to a hard disk, along with its partitions and could write whatever it (the user) desires to.

Answer (score 1):

Most probably, and most of it.

With some media (magnetic type), this is not enough to obscure the recording completely... there may be some remnant "under" the new recording. One cannot read that the normal way, but with lab equipment, it's entirely possible. That's why "erasing with a pattern" was invented (see Wikipedia on [data remanence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_remanence)).

Even "erasing with a pattern" will also *not* touch any blocks which in the meantime have been marked as "defect" (and replaced by supernumerary blocks)... they too might contain sensitive data, readable with lab equipment.

So what action to take depends largely on the thread scenario. If it's your private machine with holiday pictures, overwriting will do. If you have been handling top-secret data: shredding, dissolving in acid, [employing angle grinder/drill](https://www.theguardian.com/uk-news/2014/jan/31/footage-released-guardian-editors-snowden-hard-drives-gchq) or [melting the drive with thermite](https://frank.geekheim.de/?p=2423) might be the way to go.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I thought that operating systems had complete control over the hard drive (its heads, cylinders, tracks, sectors, whatever they are). What about a SSD?

Comment: SSDs give the OS even less control.

Comment: With magnetic media, all the head/cyl/track/sector data have been kind of "fake" (i.e. "logical" coordinates instead of "physical") since the on-board controller took over all the defect remapping. And what @K7AAY writes is absolutely correct - no physical remanence, so writing a pattern is a good start, but the bad block management problem will persist - and SSDs have *lots* of spare capacity to mask bad blocks (the controller will decide when attempting to write+verify, so usually bad blocks are not associated with data loss, but some of your data won't get deleted as expected).